# Polynomial $P(x)$ with degree $1998$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

$P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 1998 such that $P(k) = \frac{1}{k} $ for all values of $k = 1,2,3,...,1999$. What is the value of $P(2000)$?

I did try to substitute as $k = 2000$ but the highest number is $1999$. Can anyone help me with this question, it was really difficult for me, thanks.

Comment: Hint: What are the zeros of $xP(x)-1$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $Q(x)=xP(x)-1$. Then $Q(x)$ has roots $1,2,\dots,1999$ and is degree $1999$, so:

$$Q(x)=C(x-1)\dots(x-1999)$$ for some constant $C$.

Since $Q(0)=-1$, we see that $C=\frac{1}{1999!}$, and hence $Q(2000)=1$.

Now $P(x)=\frac{Q(x)+1}{x}$. So $P(2000) = \frac{2}{2000}=\frac{1}{1000}$.

**Side note**: Technically, you can skip figuring out the value of $C$ since you really only need $Q(2000)$, and pretty obviously, $Q(2000)=(-1)^{1999}Q(0) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, but can I ask how I would've been able to deduce that $Q(x) = xP(x) - 1$? I am a little confused on how I would've been able to deduce that on my own.

Comment: It's pretty much right there in the condition $Q(k)=1/k$ - multiply by $k$ and we get $kQ(k)=1,$ or $kQ(k)-1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $Q(X)=XP(X)-1-\frac{(X-1)(X-2)\cdots(X-1999)}{1999!}$ has degree less than $2000$ and vanishes $2000$ times at $0,1,2,\ldots,1999$. So it must be identically zero.
So
$$
P(2000)=\frac{1}{2000}\left(1+\frac{1999!}{1999!}\right)=\frac{1}{1000}.
$$

Comment: Wait, the constant term of your $Q(X)$ is *not* zero. How can it be identically zero? You've assumed $P(X)$ is monic here when you concluded that $Q(X)$ is degree less than $1999$.